# Is there a more rigorous way to show these two sums are exactly equal?

Tags: proof-verification, alternative-proof

### I would like to have a more rigorous proof of the hypothesis: The Crandall eta derivative series is equal to the following more elementary one.

The following two series give the same sum.

They are

$$-\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{(-1)^n  \eta ^{(n)}(n)}{n!}$$

and

$$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } (-1)^n \left(n^{\frac{1}{n}}-1\right).$$

@Gottfried Helms

made the following proof that is correct as far as the arithmetic and numeric evaluation of the eta derivatives from the logs. However, even as a novice, I think it lacks any formal proving power to show, logarithms do add up to exactly the eta derivatives! I think he was just pointing out to me that there is some trivialness in equating the two sums.

> [sic]

By use a series for

$n^{1/n} = \exp(\log n/n)$ and laying the two series: $$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } (-1)^n \left(n^{\frac{1}{n}}-1\right)$$ and $$-\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{(-1)^n  \eta ^{(n)}(n)}{n!}$$
 out in two dimensions:

$$ \begin{array} {rclll} 
 -\exp( {\log(1) \over 1})+1 & = & -{\log(1) \over 1} 
                                   &-{\log(1)^2 \over 1^2 2!}
                                   &-{\log(1)^3 \over 1^3 3!} & - \cdots \\
 +\exp( {\log(2) \over 2})-1 & = &+{\log(2) \over 2} 
                                   &+{\log(2)^2 \over 2^2 2!}
                                   &+{\log(2)^3 \over 2^3 3!} & + \cdots \\
 -\exp( {\log(3) \over 3})+1 & = &-{\log(3) \over 3} 
                                   &-{\log(3)^2 \over 3^2 2!}
                                   &-{\log(3)^3 \over 3^3 3!} & - \cdots \\
    \vdots \qquad                  & \vdots & \quad\vdots & \quad\vdots& \quad\vdots
         & \ddots \\
\hline \\
    B \qquad & = &   {\eta^{(1)}(1) \over 1!} 
                  &- {\eta^{(2)}(2) \over 2!} 
                  &+ {\eta^{(3)}(3) \over 3!} & - \cdots
\end{array}$$

Can you improve his partial proof?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even though one has cause to be a little bit wary around formal rearrangements of conditionally convergent sums (see the [Riemann series theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_series_theorem)), it's not very difficult to validate the formal manipulation of Helms. The idea is to cordon off a big chunk of the infinite double summation (all the terms from the second column on) that we know is *absolutely* convergent, which we are then free to rearrange with impunity. (Most relevantly for our purposes here, see pages 80-85 of this [document](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~hunter/intro_analysis_pdf/ch4.pdf), culminating with the Fubini theorem which is essentially the manipulation Helms is using.)

So, by definition the MRB constant $B$ is the conditionally convergent sum $\sum_{n \geq 1} (-1)^n (n^{1/n} - 1)$. Put $a_n = (-1)^n (n^{1/n} - 1)$, so $B = \sum_{n \geq 1} a_n$. Looking at the first column, put $b_n = (-1)^n \frac{\log(n)}{n}$, so $\eta^{(1)}(1) = \sum_{n \geq 1} b_n$ as a conditionally convergent series.

We have

$$B - \eta^{(1)} = \sum_{n \geq 1} a_n - b_n = \sum_{n \geq 1} \sum_{m \geq 2} (-1)^n \frac{(\log n)^m}{n^m m!}$$

(The first equation is an elementary limit statement that says if $\sum_{n \geq 1} a_n$ converges and $\sum_{n \geq 1} b_n$ converges, then also $\sum_{n \geq 1} a_n - b_n$ converges and $\sum_{n \geq 1} a_n - \sum_{n \geq 1} b_n = \sum_{n \geq 1} a_n - b_n$. It doesn't at all matter whether the convergence of either series is conditional or absolute.)

So now we check the *absolute* convergence of the right-hand side, i.e., that $\sum_{n \geq 1} \sum_{m \geq 2} \frac{(\log n)^m}{n^m m!}$ converges. (Remember what this means in the case of infinite sums of *positive* terms: it means that there is a number $K$ such that every finite partial sum $S$ is bounded above by $K$; the least such upper bound will be the number that the infinite sum converges to.) So take any such finite partial sum $S$, and rearrange its terms so that the terms in the $m = 2$ column come first, then the terms in the $m = 3$ column, and so on. An upper bound for the terms of $S$ in the $m = 2$ column is $\frac{\zeta^{(2)}(2)}{2!}$. Put that one aside.

For the $m = 3$ column, an upper bound is $\sum_{n \geq 2} \frac{(\log n)^3}{n^3 3!}$ (we drop the $n=1$ term which is $0$). By calculus we have $\log n \leq n^{1/2}$ for all $n \geq 2$, so this has upper bound $\frac1{3!} \sum_{n \geq 2} \frac1{n^{3/2}} \leq \frac1{3!} \int_1^\infty \frac{dx}{x^{3/2}}$ by an integral test, which yields $\frac{2}{3!}$ as an upper bound. Applying the same reasoning for the $m$ column from $m = 4$ on, an upper bound for that column would be $\frac1{m!} \int_1^\infty \frac{dx}{x^{m/2}} = \frac{2}{m!(m-2)}$. Adding all those upper bounds together, an upper bound for the entire doubly infinite sum would be

$$\frac{\zeta^{(2)}(2)}{2!} + \sum_{m \geq 3} \frac{2}{m!(m-2)}$$

which certainly converges. So we have absolute convergence of the doubly infinite sum.

Thus we are in a position to apply the Fubini theorem, which justifies the rearrangement expressed in the first of the following equations

$$\sum_{n \geq 1} \sum_{m \geq 2} (-1)^n \frac{(\log n)^m}{n^m m!} = \sum_{m \geq 2} \sum_{n \geq 1} (-1)^n \frac{(\log n)^m}{n^m m!} = \sum_{m \geq 2} (-1)^{m+1} \frac{\eta^{(m)}(m)}{m!}$$

giving us what we wanted.

Comment: I  understood most of that. Thanks! I will take  apart until I fully understand.

Comment: Take your time; glad to help.